# How to remove commented block from a file?

Tags: python, regex

In that there is a commented block as `/*..*/` and `<<`, `>>`, `!!` symbols, I need to copy the contents of this file in another file, while removing commented block and other symbols.

For example:

```
/*
author : xyz
date : 23/08/2015
this block is only for reference
*/
? fill j.dat 
!!
a1  hi   hello
b1  red orange
!!
? fill s.dat 
<<
>>
actual content of the file.
```

I want to copy only `actual content of the file` to another file. Is there any regex I can use to avoid this?

Comment: Is it all at the start?

Comment: Are the symbols always at the start of the line?

Comment: try this regex `(/\*(.*)\*/|<<(.*)>>|!!(.*)!!)`, [regex link](https://regex101.com/r/xG4eI9/3)

Comment: Tried all the given solution, but with that only the characters " *, <<, >>, ! , ?" are getting removed. characters between them are still present inthe output.

Comment: You need to be more specific about the grammar of your comments. Is `?` a one line comment? Are `!!` and `>>..<<` equivalent to `/*` and `*/` as multiline comments? Are you supporting `//` one line C comments?

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use this regular expression for that

```
\/\*([\s\S]*?)\*\/
```

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/vJ8qL0/1)

Answer (score 0):

The following regular expression substitution could be used for your sample text, but it probably not cope well with nested sections:

```
import re

text = """/*
author : xyz
date : 23/08/2015
this block is only for reference
*/
? fill j.dat 
!!
a1  hi   hello
b1  red orange
!!
? fill s.dat 
<<
>>
actual content of the file.  """

print re.sub("((\/\*.*?\*\/)|(<<.*?>>)|(!!.*?!!)|(^\? .*?$))" , "", text, flags=re.S+re.M).lstrip("\n")
```

This would display:

```
actual content of the file.
```

These would be removed from anywhere in the file, not just at the start.

Comment: Tried above solution, but I am not getting the desired output as "actual contents of the file.", instead of this, following is the output: / author : xyz
date : 23/08/2015
this block is only for reference/ fill j.dat  a1  hi   hello b1  red orange fill s.dat

Comment: That is odd, I have just copy pasted the exact script above back and retested it and it gives the correct output on Python 2.7.9

Comment: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lQ3wO7/1) shows the text all correctly matched.

Answer (score 0):

When I used re.sub, I didn't get the desired result, but after using re.compile, within that, I was able to get the result. I've used the following to get the desired output,  but I had to get it in more than one step. The following is my code.

```
str1 = re.sub(re.compile("((/\*.*?\*/)|(<<.*?>>)|(!!.*?!!)|(\? (.*)?\?)|)", re.DOTALL), "", contents)
str1 = re.sub(re.compile('^[^\*]*\*', re.DOTALL), "", str1)
str1 = re.sub(re.compile('(?m)^\*', re.DOTALL), "", str1)
str1 = re.sub("(;\\\g)|(\\\g)", ';', str1)
```